# IE9 and lake.js

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using the [lake.js jquery plugin](http://alligator.github.com/lake.js/) on a page and in order for it to work/look proper you have to use display:none;

On IE9, whatever fires and makes the image visible in the script won't work. It keeps it invisible. On everything else it works fine.

I was wondering if anyone here might know the answer or reason behind this because the author has yet to answer this issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
 style="display: inline-block;visibility:hidden;"/>
```

http://www.hoekern.com/lake/index.php

working in ie9 ere at least;

Comment: Let me get back to you on that. Apparently IE9 has randomly decided nothing will work right now so I can't test it.